# LDAP Query to find ALL managers of a user

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is it possible, using LDAP filter syntax, to retrieve all users a user is subordinate to, based on the 'manager' attribute? For example,

- Bob is John's manager
- Alice is Bob's manager
- Dave is Alice's manager
- Mary is Dave's manager

When I give John's user account, I get Bob, Alice, Dave and Mary.

I know this can be done the other way around using LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN, e.g.

**(manager:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=cn=mary,ou=bosses,dc=domain,dc=local)**

...would return Dave, Alice, Bob and John's user accounts (per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746475(v=vs.85).aspx) article):

My question is - in the absence of a corresponding linked attribute (such as in the case of member and memberof), can this be achieved using filter syntax? I know this can be achieved programmatically but I'm trying to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of the manager attribute is directReports.

So you can use the chain rule to match this to get all managers above:
`(directreports:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=JOHNS-DN-HERE)`

Comment: Well I stand corrected, thanks! I wrongly assumed that as I couldn't see any such attribute in ADSIEdit, it didn't exist, but it must be a dynamic attribute assessed at query time. Works perfectly, thanks!